# Make [dnn] a synonym of [deep-network]

Tags: support, retag-request

[dnn](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnn) just stands for deep neural network, which we already have a tag for: [deep-network](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-network). Can we just synonymize these?

Comment: There is also [tag:deep-learning]

Comment: @kenorb Yeah, but [dnn] stands for [deep-network].

Comment: @RobertCartaino Since you took the time to remove the [tags] tag, can you take the time to do these? :P